# highlightFill for radar charts in chartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The bar charts in chartJS can change the fill color on highlight, using the highlightFill property:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-data-structure

```
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]};
```

The radar charts however, have no such property:

```
var data = {
    labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
        }
    ]
};
```

Any ideas for how I might be able to extend the radar chart to be able to use that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radar chart is different from the bar chart in that, *an* area is actually an entire series (for bar chart it is a single data point).

When you get a radar tooltip, and you think about what area of the chart it represents, you realize that it basically represents just 2 points radiating from the center. The *area* between 2 points of a series is actually shared between them. Highlighting half the area would not look nice either.

[image]

Add to that, the fact that one radar chart series could be completely covered by the 2nd one, I can't think of a non-confusing way to have a hover highlight for a radar chart (just think of how you would do highlighting for a line chart *area* - you don't. You do it only for a point)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @potatopeelings! I'm actually just trying to hide a dataset on hover, so I can "highlight" the remaining dataset. I figured having a highlight property would be able to solve that pretty easily.. But maybe I should just remove the dataset on mouse leave.

Comment: You'd run into the same problem I think. If you have 1 dataset completely covering the other, like in the last picture, you wouldn't be able to hide the inner one.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'll always be hiding the same dataset, so I think I can make it work by being specific about that